# Intercept request & send to external

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring boot project.

One example of my controller:

```
@Controller
public class RestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/student/{studentId}")
    public @ResponseBody Student getData(@PathVariable Integer studentId) {
        Student student = new Student();
        student.setName("Peter");
        student.setId(studentId);

        return student;
    }
}
```

I have other endpoints implemented as well.

I need to intercept every request hits my endpoints & forward the request to another service (microservice), in other words, I need to forward each request to another web app running on the same local machine as current one, based on the response from that service to decide whether proceed forward the request or not.

My rough idea is to use [HandlerIntercept](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) , but I am not sure whether I am going to the right direction. Could someone please share some experiences what is the best way to achieve this?  It would be nice if you could show some sample code.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HandlerInterceptorAdapter.

Define the Interceptor as below.

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("In preHandle we are Intercepting the Request");
        System.out.println("____________________________________________");
        //Call the Rest API and Validate 
        if (conditionsNotMet()) {
           response.getWriter().write("something");
           response.setStatus(someErrorCode);

           return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Register the HandlerInterceptorAdapter

```
@Configuration
public class PathMatchingConfigurationAdapter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
    }
}
```

using WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class PathMatchingConfigurationAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry resourceHandlerRegistry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry corsRegistry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry viewControllerRegistry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry viewResolverRegistry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public void extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> list) {

    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageCodesResolver getMessageCodesResolver() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer asyncSupportConfigurer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer defaultServletHandlerConfigurer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know how to use HandlerInterceptorAdapter, but 1. how to forward the request to the other service?  2, how to based on the response from the other service proceed forward the request object when response true or discard the request when response false (let's say the response of the other service for this request is a boolean flag)?

Comment: You can use the HttpServletRequest to get the inputs and make rest API call inside the preHandle method. Depending upon the validation you can return true or false.

Comment: Do you mean in reHandle method, return true would proceed forward the request & return false would discard the request?

Comment: If preHandle method returns ‘false’ Spring framework assumes that request has been handled by the spring interceptor itself and no further processing is needed. We should use the response object to send the response to the client request in this case.

Comment: Yes, exactly, so, the question I have is how to response to client the response object based on the other service responsed boolean?

Comment: If preHandle method returns false after validation then rest-api will discard the request and won't proceed further . It will return Http Status code 200 to the Caller.

Comment: So, are you saying in preHandle method it doesn't matter it returns true or false it eventually return 200 to client for both cases? Because you are saying return false also returns status code 200. But if I want to return to client e.g. 422 with customized error object in response object, how to do that?

Comment: I have updated the answer to send a custom error code. But your original question was based on the response from the validation service to decide whether to proceed forward the request or not.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated.

Comment: use WebMvcConfigurer 
https://www.baeldung.com/web-mvc-configurer-adapter-deprecated

Comment: Now, the preHandle() get triggered twice for one request. What's the best way to get rid of that?

Comment: I have updated the answer with WebMvcConfigurer. It is getting invoked only once. Not sure why it is happening twice in your case.